# Submit PHP form once javascript validation is successful

Tags: php, javascript, validation

When I submit my form, I get my javascript validation messages which is correct but the form is still submitted and I get the php validation messages. How can I only submit my form if the javascript tests are passed:

Form:

```
enter code here// first name is mandatory
if (!$firstName) {
$msg_to_user = '<h4 class="errmsg"><font color="FF0000">Please enter your first name.</font></h4>';

// email is mandatory
} else if (!$email) {
$msg_to_user = '<h4 class="errmsg"><font color="FF0000">Please type an email address ' . $firstName . '.</font></h4>';

// check email is valid
} else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$msg_to_user = '<h4 class="errmsg"><font color="FF0000">' . $email . ' is not a valid email address.</font></h4>';

// check postcode is a number
} else if (!empty($postcode) && !is_numeric($postcode))  {  
$msg_to_user = '<h4 class="errmsg"><font color="FF0000">Postcode must be a numeric value.</font></h4>';

// check postcode is greater than 4 chars
} else if (!empty($postcode) && (strlen ($postcode) < 4)) {
$msg_to_user = '<h4 class="errmsg"><font color="FF0000">Postcode must be at least 4 characters.</font></h4>';

// check postcode is less than 12 chars
} else if (strlen ($postcode) > 12) {
$msg_to_user = '<h4 class="errmsg"><font color="FF0000">Postcode must be less than 12 characters.</font></h4>';

// check email doesn't exist    
} else if ($numRows > 0) {
$msg_to_user = '<h4 class="errmsg"><font color="FF0000">' . $email . ' is already in the system.</font></h4>';

// if all test passed, insert details into database
} else {
$sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (firstName, lastName, email, postcode, dateTime) 
                                                VALUES('$firstName','$lastName','$email','$postcode',now() )") or die(mysql_error());

$subscribed = '<h4 class="submsg"><font color="0066FF">Thanks ' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . ', ' . $email . '  has been subscribed to our newsletter.</font></h4>';
?>



<form name="newsletter" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];" ?>    
id="newsletter" onSubmit="postcodeval(); emailval(); notnull();">
<fieldset>
  <label for="firstName" id="firstName_label">First Name*:</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="36" value="<?php echo isset($firstName) ? $firstName : '' ?>" class="text-input" onBlur="notnull()" />
  <br />
  <label for="lastName" id="lastName_label">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="36" value="<?php echo isset($lastName) ? $lastName : '' ?>" class="text-input" />
  <br />
  <label for="email" id="email_label">Email*:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="36" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['submit_newsletter'])){echo $_SESSION['newsletterSignup'];} ?><?php echo isset($email) ? $email : '' ?>" class="text-input" onBlur="emailval()" />
  <br />
  <label for="postcode" id="postcode_label">Postcode:</label>
  <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" size="12" value="<?php echo isset($postcode) ? $postcode : '' ?>" class="text-input" onBlur="postcodeval()" />
    <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Subscribe" />
</fieldset>
```

Javascript:

```
    //Name cannot be blank
function notnull() {
var z = document.forms["newsletter"]["firstName"].value;
if (z === null || z === "") {
    inlineMsg('firstName', 'You must enter your name.', 3);
    return false;
}
}


//Vaidate email address
function emailval() {
var y = document.forms["newsletter"]["email"].value;
var atpos = y.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = y.lastIndexOf(".");
if (y === null || y === "") {
 inlineMsg('email', 'You must enter an email.', 3);
}       
if (y === null || y === "") {
    return true;
}
if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= y.length) {
    inlineMsg('email', 'Not a valid e-mail address.', 3);
    return false;
}
}


//Vaidate postcode
function postcodeval() {
var x = document.forms["newsletter"]["postcode"].value;
if(!!x){
    if (isNaN(x)) {
 inlineMsg('postcode', 'Must be numbers only.', 3);
}   

else if (x.length < 4) {
 inlineMsg('postcode', 'Must be more than than 4 characters.', 3);
}   

 else if (x.length > 12) {
 inlineMsg('postcode', 'Must be less than 12 characters.', 3);
}

}else{
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In form onSubmit you have to use return in function call.

```
<form name="newsletter" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];" ?>    
id="newsletter" onSubmit=" return postcodeval(); return emailval(); return notnull();">
```

Comment: Relax dude. Did not even vote you down. Fix your script, you can only have one return

Comment: Ok dude. You have did that. You from? Can i have your mail id. So that we can have some KT ?

Comment: KT ? - Knowledge Transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the console for errors. Your validation needs to run onsubmit and return true if valid, false if not. Any errors in the actual script will allow submission

For example

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)" ...>
```

Where validate is

```
function validate(theForm) {
  return nameval(theForm) &&
         emailval(theForm) &&
         postcodeval(theForm);
}

//Name cannot be blank
function nameval(theForm) {
  var name = theForm["firstName"].value;
  if (name === "") { // cannot be null
    inlineMsg('firstName', 'You must enter your name.', 3);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


//Vaidate email address
function emailval(theForm) {
  var email = theForm["email"].value;
  if (email === "") {
   inlineMsg('email', 'You must enter an email.', 3);
   return false;
  }       
  var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= y.length) {
    inlineMsg('email', 'Not a valid e-mail address.', 3);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


//Vaidate postcode
function postcodeval(theForm) {
  var postCode = theForm["postcode"].value;
  if(postCode !=="") { // postcode is not mandatory
    if (isNaN(postCode)) {
      inlineMsg('postcode', 'Must be numbers only.', 3);
      return false;
    }   
    if (postCode.length < 4) {
      inlineMsg('postcode', 'Must be more than than 4 characters.', 3);
      return false;
    }   
    if (postCode.length > 12) {
      inlineMsg('postcode', 'Must be less than 12 characters.', 3);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```